# Asp.Net Core app not working with other areas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have published this app which is still under testing. I used the asp.net core identity framework for my security. When I publish the app without adding other things like dashboard pages, everything works fine and I can route to the `/Identity/Account/Manage/index` page and see my profile. Now I added a new area called dashboard and created some pages like categories, tags etc. These are all in their respective folders. This is now the structure of the program
Areas
--Dashboard
---Pages
----Categories
------index.cshtml
------create.cshtml
----Tags
------index.cshtml
------create.cshtml
--Identity
---Pages
----Account

Now Ive deployed the app to this website but it doesn't go to the areas under dashboard. Even the area under identity too does not navigate again. The areas under dashboard are recognized but they just show blank when i navigate to it. You can use this password and username to login and see what im talking about. Username:**OpMainControl** Password:**room?@awaitcash#**  This is the website http://www.masterlet.com After you login, you can try navigating to the usual Identity pages like
/Account/Identity/Manage or /Account/Identity/Manage/changepassword. Or you use the new area i created at /Dashboard/tags and /Dashboard/categories. Ive been trying to manuever this thing for almost 5 days now with no avail. Please help!!

Comment: Which version of asp.net?  Areas was not automatic in 2.X (but it is automatic in 3.x)

Comment: im using 2.2 If the above url doen't open please use this http://versionx-001-site1.atempurl.com/

Comment: You may also want to know that every area works okay in local mode until I publish it.

Comment: Do you have all the .cshtml files marked as 'Content'?

Comment: What do you mean by marked as 'Content'?

Comment: Get the properties for the cshtml file, and the Build Action should be Content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212095/discussion-between-formula12-and-neil).

Comment: [Area("Articles")]

    public class ArticleController : Controller

Comment: @JohnMeek im using Razor pages not mvc. Though this also happens to me when im creating an mvc project also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Area endpoint in the startup.cs?

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
               endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: " 
  {area:exists=Articles}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
               endpoints.MapRazorPages();
          });
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it seems that is for Asp.Net Core 3.x

Comment: app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});